# Heroku could not find or load main class on one-off dyno

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I am trying to split my Heroku application into a web process and another non-web process that could run on a one-off dyno.

My directory looks something like this:

```
app/
  pom.xml
  src/
    main/
      java/
        Main.java
```

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    ...
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <useWildcardClassPath>true</useWildcardClassPath>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        <name>oneoff</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0.34.0</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

After I `mvn package`, everything and try to run `sh target/bin/oneoff`, it says

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly= true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
Error: Could not find or load main class Main.
```

I get this error both locally on Windows bash and on Heroku. However, it works when I use the batch counterpart, `target\bin\oneoff.bat` on Windows.

I even tried to run it by doing `java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main` on both heroku through `heroku run` and locally which results in the same error.

Comment: from where you invoked that `java`

Comment: I invoked it through `heroku run` and on bash locally.